# Where does GIMP/Fontconfig store built-in fonts on Windows?

Tags: fonts, gimp

I use GIMP on Windows. It comes with lots of pre-installed fonts; one example is the "Sans" font. I'm trying to locate where these fonts are stored on disk in Windows.

[The documentation says the following:](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-fonts.html)

> **GIMP uses the FreeType 2 font engine to render fonts, and a system called Fontconfig to manage them. GIMP will let you use any font in Fontconfig's font path**; it will also let you use any font it finds in GIMP's font search path, which is set on the Font Folders page of the Preferences dialog. By default, the font search path includes a system GIMP-fonts folder (which you should not alter, even though it is actually empty), and a fonts folder inside your personal GIMP directory. You can add new folders to the font search path if it is more convenient for you.

I can't find the fonts in GIMP's own font search path. How can I find Fontconfig's font path on Windows?

Just to show that I've covered the other options mentioned in that example... If I go to "Preferences -> Folders -> Fonts", I see that my GIMP installation has two font folders configured:

- C:\Users\.gimp-2.8\fonts
- C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\fonts

The first folder is empty, and the second does not exist. This fits with [what the documentation says](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-fonts.html); I haven't added any custom fonts, so that's OK.

For Windows, it also says this further down the page:

> **Windows.**  The easiest way to install a font is to drag the file onto the Fonts directory and let the shell do its magic. Unless you've done something creative, it's probably in its default location of `C:\windows\fonts` or `C:\winnt\fonts`. Sometimes double-clicking on a font will install it as well as display it; sometimes it only displays it. This method will make the font available not only to GIMP, but also to other Windows applications.

The fonts in question are not located in `C:\windows\fonts` either.

So the last place I assume these fonts can be located is in the Fontconfig folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, Gimp fonts come from two sources:

- the fonts installed as system fonts on Windows (Arial, Comic Sans, etc...)
- the fonts installed in Gimp-specific directories, that only Gimp sees (none, until you add some)

All this is managed by the fontconfig system, which uses a cache: on Windows this is in C:\users{your id}\AppData\local\fontconfig) but normally you don't deal directly with this directory.

In addition, the `Sans`, `Serif` and `Monospace` fonts do not correspond to specific fonts, they are really just a way to name a default font of the corresponding type: on Windows `Sans` is likely `Arial` while on Linux it would be `Liberation`. They make good default values (for scripts, etc...) since they are always there, whatever the OS and version.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the information about "Sans". I didn't catch that nuance (not sure if it's clear from the UI). I do have other examples though, but they're mostly different font weights. "Impact Condensed" is another example; I find the font "Impact" in my Windows font directory, but it doesn't contain a Condensed variation.